# using linux framebuffer for graphics but disabling console text

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer

I have some c code that draws simple graphics on the linux framebuffer console. I'm also using the raspberry pi and it's composite video output. The OS is raspbian, and i'm doing a low level solution without using X.

My graphics are working well, and i'm also able to read the usb keyboard and respond to key presses.

Currently there is a tty terminal that my graphics are written over. The tty is still active and key presses are echoed to the screen.

What I want to achieve is to disable all console messages and ttys on the framebuffer so only my graphics are shown. Does anyone have a good way of doing this? Perhaps disabling the tty on that virtual console?

Rob

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is `ioctl(fd, KDSETMODE, KD_GRAPHICS)`. You'll need to set it back before you exit.